# Setting value of array using combobox selected index

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set up an empty array first and then trying to set the value of the array depending on the selected index of the combobox. The code will make more sense

```
        double[] xValues = {};

        private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                double[] xValues = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                return xValues;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                double[] xValues = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
                return xValues;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                double[] xValues = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
                return xValues;
            }
        }
```

But on the error console I'm getting three errors:

> Error  1   Since 'StepTestOne.Form1.comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object, System.EventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI this question has nothing to do with visual studio. It seems you've actually left out the important tag, is this WinForms, WebForms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms... Thanks for pointing that out and I'm using VS hence the tag

Comment: Right, but if you're using WinForms it's inferred that you're using Visual Studio. With your logic you'll need to put the Windows 7, Computer and Office Desk tags... In other words the question isn't specifically "How do I do this in Visual Studio". It's specific to WinForms and C#. I'm telling you this so you get the best exposure from questions in the future.

Comment: LOL... good point @The Muffin Man I'll take it into account from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove:

```
return xValues;
```

The return type is void, which means nothing should be returned. But, if you had something like:

```
private string getString()
{
 return "some string";
}
```

Then, a return value of string is expected.

Comment: @MikeG Thanks.. I do want a return as I intend to use `xValues` somewhere else.. what should I do? my guess is to add `getString()` inside the `private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` Am I right?

Comment: Just have  "somewhere else" have access to xValues which you declared outside of combobox1_SelectedValueChanged. Once the selected values change, the xValues loads, so you don't have to return it, just have it accessible to be read elsewhere.

Comment: You are right! I've tested it and it actually sets the values depending on the selection! Thanks man!