# Array value resets automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Ok this silly problem is connected to the post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940719/setting-value-of-array-using-combobox-selected-index). What I did is basically removed the `return` and was able to set the values of the `xValues` array depending on combobox selection index. as per this pic [image]
But as I try to call another method to divide certain variable with `xValues.Length` it gives me `'System.DivideByZeroException` error as the value for `xValues` and `xValues.Length` resets to zero. Here is the code snippet:

```
int[] xValues = { }; //declaring empty array

private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //using selection
                                                                        //to set the xValues
{
      if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        int[]xValues= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
       int[] xValues = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        int[] xValues = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    }        
}
```

And then lets say I'm calling a method `doSomeThing()`

```
public void doSomeThing()
{
    int bSum = bValues.Sum(); //bValues comes from different input and in debugger 
                              //it shows expected values.
    int aSum = xValues.Sum(); //Here the debugger tells me aSum doesn't exists
    int slope = bSum / xValues.Length; //Divided by zero exception error goes here.
}
```

Why and how the the values are resetting for `xValues`?

Comment: Please don't add screenshots which are unconnected to the rest of your question. (The second one doesn't show the code that your question asks about.)

Comment: I've added only to show that that didnt work... removed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

waka's answer is right about what's wrong - you're declaring new local variables which are *entirely independent* of the instance variable.

However, waka's fix isn't quite right - you can only initialize arrays in that particular way at the point of the declaration of the variable. To assign a new value to the variable, you need slightly different syntax:

```
xValues = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Or if you want to specify the element type explicitly:

```
xValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: whoa... you are right mate... lol one missing syntax.. it worsks now... :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are not resetting anything. You declare a new int array (as in: a new object) every time the selected value changes! That's why the length of the array in the other method is always 0: Because it's still the global empty int array.

```
int[] xValues = { }; //declaring empty array

private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //using selection
                                                                        //to set the xValues
{
      if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        xValues= new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
       xValues = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        xValues = new int[] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    }        
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that already and itvdoesn't work..:( as soon as I do this `xValues= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` it underlines all the values and tells me `;` expected.

Comment: check the screenshot.

Comment: Of course Jon Skeet is right about how to assign new values to an array. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Set the length of the xValues array to five if it will always be five. I.e

```
int[] xValues =new int[5];
```

Then in your if statements just assign the xValues array the new values i.e.

```
xValues =new {1,2,3,4,5};
```

You never told the computer how big the array was. But by saying

```
  int[]xValues xValues =new {1,2,3,4,5}
```

You are changing the scope for that variable; you are not actually referencing the original xValues array

Comment: Thanks @Richard Barker 
I prefer to use `xValues.Length` as I can update the code more easily at a later date if the number of values changes to more than five `.Length` will update it automatically